# Excel VBA clear data function protects cell not previously not protected

Tags: excel, vba

When I first open my workbook I call this function to protect specific cell ranges and cells from the user:

```
' Sets protection on sheet
Public Sub LockCells_TXN_CLIENT_ORDER_ENTRY()
  ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="abc"
  ActiveSheet.Cells.Locked = False
  ' Lock some cells here
  ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="abc"
End Sub
```

However, upon calling the following Subrouting to clear data from a range of rows:

```
Private Sub ClearData_Click()
  ' Declare some variables

  For currentRow = ActiveSheet.Range("STATUS_FIELDS").Row To totalRows
    ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow, ActiveSheet.Range("STATUS_FIELDS").Column).Resize(1, 14).Clear
  Next currentRow
End Sub
```

Cells that were not specified to be protected now becomes protected and these cells are the exact same cells that the `ClearData_Click()` function affected.

Could someone please explain to me why this happens and how to avoid this?

Comment: just a quick thought - not sure if it helps or not - but the use of `ActiveCells` and `ActiveSheet` can be dangerous in that it can affect things you don't intend. Perhaps you could qualify the exact sheets and ranges you want to work with and thus avoid having unexpected things occur in the code?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, Hi Scott, where do you see ActiveCells?

Comment: my bad. It was just `ActiveSheet`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of `.Clear` is causing the problem.

Either use `.ClearContents` instead, or re-set the locked property after you clear the range.

`.Clear` clears the entire object, including the part where you set its locked property to false.

Comment: thanks a lot you are right. However, I also set the fill of this cell, so I guess resetting the `Lock` properties is the only choice?

Comment: I would use `.clearcontents`. That way your locked property, your fill, and whatever else you've done to the range will remain intact. If that doesn't work for some reason, use `.clear` and reset everything that got cleared.